# C# updating listview item manually

Tags: c#, winforms

I add an item to the listview manually so when i try to edit the text of it, it just adds a new item instead of editing it.

Can someone point to where the problem is..?

```
    public void UpdateStatus(string Message, int index = 00)
    {
        while (!this.IsHandleCreated)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
        if (index == 00)
        {
            listView1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate {
                string[] message1 = { Message };
                ListViewItem list = new ListViewItem(message1);
                listView1.Items.Add(list);
            });
        } else if (index != 00)
        {
            listView1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate {
                string[] message1 = { Message };
                ListViewItem list = new ListViewItem(message1);
                //listView1.Items.RemoveAt(index);
                listView1.Items[0].SubItems[0].Text = Message;
            });
        }

    }
```

Comment: im using winforms

Comment: Am I understanding that if index is zero you want to add a ListViewItem to the ListView and if the index is not 00 that you just want to update the ListViewItem that was added when index was zero with Message?

Comment: Use your debugger to see the `index` value when you assign `index = 0` or `= 00`, or even `= 0000000000000`.

Comment: @dr.null Thank you! that solved the issue. For some reason it wasnt passing the index.